# How can I fix this error AsyncDrawableCache.java in firebase Crashlytics crash reports

Tags: java, android

I get an error on the following line in my firebase Crashlytics crash reports .Please help me.

```
AsyncDrawableCache.java
```

> Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
> android.util.ArrayMap.put (ArrayMap.java:620)
> com.mediatek.res.AsyncDrawableCache.putCacheList (AsyncDrawableCache.java:163)
> com.mediatek.res.ResOptExtImpl.putCacheList (ResOptExtImpl.java:69)
> android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.cacheDrawable (ResourcesImpl.java:832)
> android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable (ResourcesImpl.java:769)
> android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:1002)
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity (TypedArray.java:1006)
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:981)
> android.widget.ImageView. (ImageView.java:215)
> android.widget.ImageView. (ImageView.java:196)
> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView. (AppCompatImageView.java:74)
> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView. (AppCompatImageView.java:69)
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:1065)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:995)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:959)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1138)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1099)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1141)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1099)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1141)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1099)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1141)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1099)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1141)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1099)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:680)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:532)
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:479)
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
> mobitech.dconproject.MotorStatus.onCreate (mainActivity.java:232)
> android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8151)
> android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8135)
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1309)
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3732)
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3931)
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2356)
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
> android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:264)
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8306)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:632)
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1049)